# How to properly insert text at the current position in Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

**Question**

How can I insert text into a Tkinter Textbox? I am trying to create a word processor which inserts lists at the current position.

**What I have tried so far**

I have tried to use the `CURRENT` argument, but this is unreliable.

```
def listcmd(self): #THIS HAS BUGS!!! FIX IT SOON
    number = self.listentry.get()
    number = int(number)
    listINT = 1

    for x in xrange(number):
        self.write.insert(CURRENT, "%s:" % (str(listINT) )) #This is used for the number
        self.write.insert(CURRENT, "\n") #This inserts the newline
        listINT += 1
```

Comment: In what way is it unreliable?  What do you expect vs what happens?

Comment: @StevenRumbalski thanks for pointing out the confusion. I want it to insert the list at the current cursor position (where my cursor is blinking) It inserts it at the beginning.

Comment: Aha!  Then you want `INSERT`, not `CURRENT`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the index "insert" or Tkinter.INSERT. That always refers to the insertion cursor.